# What is a quick proof that $f \in \mathbb{C}[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ is determined by its induced function on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For $f \in \mathbb{C}[X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$, we have the induced function $\bar{f}: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ given by evaluation. The association $f \mapsto \bar{f}$ is injective.

Is there a quick proof of this? Please give me some hints.

**Note:** Please close/delete this question if it has been asked before. Thanks.

**My proof:**

Induct on $n$. For $n=1$: If $\bar{f} = 0$ then for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$, the polynomial $X- x$ divides $f$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is infinite, the only way this can hold is $f = 0$.

Now assume true for $n$ and consider $n+1$. Suppose $\bar{f} = 0$. For all $x \in \mathbb{C}$, let $g_x := f|_{X_{n+1} = x} \in \mathbb{C} [X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$. Then $\overline{g_x} = 0$. The induction hypothesis implies $g_x = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$.

Write $f = f_0 + f_1 X_{n+1} + \dotsb + f_k X_{n+1}^k$ for $f_0, \dotsc, f_k \in \mathbb{C} [X_1, \dotsc, X_n]$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is infinite, we can pick distinct $x_0, \dotsc, x_k \in \mathbb{C}$. Then the result that $g_{x_j} = 0$ for each $j$ implies that the matrix $M_{ij} := f_{i} x_j^i$ has linearly dependent rows, so that $
\det{M} = 0$. But by the vandermonde determinant formula, $\det{M} = \prod_i f_{i} \prod_{i < j} (x_j - x_i)$, implying that all $f_i = 0$.

(This proof works when $\mathbb{C}$ is replaced with any infinite integral domain $R$, I think.)

**Clarification:** A quick proof means deducing the result as an easy consequence, even special case, of some general theorem.

Comment: Maybe you can decide: are you asking for a "quick proof" or for a proof verification?

Comment: The proof seems sound to me, and I agree that it works for infinite integral domains R.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Use induction on n and $C[X_1,...,X_n,X_{n+1}]=C[X_1,...,X_n][X_{n+1}]$

Comment: I'm about to edit this question so that it reflects better what I'm looking for. Obviously I knew that induction is involved---it doesn't make the proof quicker. I'd appreciate it if you could help me after my edit. Thanks