# Can the induced function of non-zero $f \in R[X]$ be zero, when $R$ is an infinite non-integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, polynomials

> Let $R$ be an infinite commutative ring with $1$ which is not an integral domain. Is it possible to have a non-zero $f\in R[X]$ such that the induced map $\bar{f}: R \to R$ is zero?

Please give me some hints. Thanks.

(Note if $R$ is finite I can take $R = \mathbb{Z}_4$ to give the answer *yes*; if $R$ is infinite and an integral domain then the answer is *no*---I proved that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/980792/71815).)

**Edit:** A problem is that I don't know many such $R$ to begin with. I know I can take $\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$ with $x$ not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ (and variants of this), or the ascending union of $\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$, but that's about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb Z_6\times\mathbb Z_6\times\cdots$, and $f\in R[X]$, $f(X)=X^3-X$.

Comment: $R = \mathbb{Z}_4^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $f(X) = 2X(X-1)$ by the same token. I was clearly overthinking...